# Having a Book that automatically stores the knowledge of the owner/attuned?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, equipment

I was thinking about what items would really help a forgetful player and I was thinking about how an item that automatically records the knowledge of the character would actually help.

My idea was that it would act as a library (as per the keen mind feat but as an attuned item instead that would require looking through the book rather them just remembering) for anything that the player wanted to be recorded whether it was a conversation, knowledge or an image/sight that the character had seen (such as text that they couldn't translate, the contents of a book that they have seen but cannot keep or the image of a person they only see briefly). I was thinking that it would have an infinite number of pages and record anything that the player thought about remembering, including spells even if they can't be cast from the book (I don't want it to be a spell book).

I was thinking of this as a narrative way to allow the player to ask the GM questions about things that they don't remember (similar to the keen mind feat) and share things from memory with other PCs or NPCs without making an intelligence check to see if they remember, for instance the image of a person if the player was the only person to see them and the character can't draw.
I also had the idea that this item could act as way to transfer information from a NPC to a player quickly, especially an image of people if the players are questioning locals about what they remember of an event. Sure players can do this by taking notes but I had hoped that if it is a useful magical item then players might use the item and then also remember to write down the information. To use the item I would probably make them keep notes, even if it was just an summary of the information stored in the book.

The book could even be found with useful knowledge in it, so that it becomes useful to the players, and could be a plot point in the future(For instance, a dying wizard the players come across, see's they have it and asks the players to touch the book and store knowledge in it as a way to pass it on to another person before he dies)

> **Book of remembrance**(Doesn't require attument)
>
> A book that allows the user to magically record any thought or memory one page long. This memory may be of anything and as complicated as you like. It can also record the memory of an image, which is replicated just as the user remembers it. To record a thought or a memory requires a bonus action and physical contact with the book. The book has an infinite number of pages and will never visibly get thicker. It looks like a plain thin leather book.

I was wondering how that could be improved, changed or balanced better. And how people think it would would affect the play of a game, or whether it even be worthwhile to have as a player?.

Comment: The site struggles to determine if *ideas* are balanced. However, if the question were to include the actual description of the item as you would have it appear in your campaign—using the format and language of similar magic items found elsewhere—, the site could offer an evaluation of that *specific* item as the question describes. (Until that hard text's available, though, the site doesn't *really* know what the item *actually* does, so answers would've had to speculate on what the item *might* do from your description of the item *might* do—and that's just too much *might*ing!)

Comment: FYI, "how to help a forgetful player remember stuff" (being your actual problem) is a wholly different issue that doesn't require a magic item to resolve. This question's an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/152515), where you're asking us about one specific solution rather than your actual problem. I suggest asking about that problem instead, unless you're certain you exclusively want this solution and you're not interested in any others. (If you wish to do that, I suggest asking a new question entirely along those lines.)